# Change logo on theme based on user role

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Flatsome theme.

I want to change the logo based on the user role of the current user.

In the flatsome-child folder I've accessed the functions.php.

Just trying to change the logo isn't working, so I've tried with some code, giving me nada change.

I've googled on how to change custom logo, but all I find is how you can change it in Wordpress, but I need to have two different logos based on user role.

```php
<?
add_filter('get_custom_logo', 'helpwp_custom_logo_output', 10);
function helpwp_custom_logo_output() {
    $html = '<a href="https://www.linkhere.com/" title="linkhere.com" rel="home">';
    $html .= '<img width="278" height="73" src="https://www.linkhere.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/linkhere-logo-custom.png" class="header_logo header-logo" alt="linkhere" scale="0">';
    $html .= '<img width="278" height="73" src="https://www.linkhere.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/linkhere-logo-custom.png" class="header-logo-dark" alt="linkhere" scale="0">';
    $html .= '</a>';

    $html = str_replace('header_logo', 'logo', $html );
    return $html;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress stores user roles as capabilities in the user meta table. You can format your page templates like so:

```
<?php if (current_user_can('administrator')) : ?>
<img src="admin_logo.png" />
<?php elseif (current_user_can('editor')) : ?>
<img src="editor_logo.png" />
<?php else : ?>
<img src="logo.png" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Give custom path  of your logo image above

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has a function called

```
current_user_can( string $capability )
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/

It returns TRUE or FALSE.

The capabilities are:
‘delete_user’, ‘edit_user’, ‘remove_user’, ‘promote_user’, ‘delete_post’, ‘delete_page’, ‘edit_post’, ‘edit_page’, ‘read_post’, or ‘read_page’

User roles are supported in part, like 'administrator' or 'editor'.

With this function you can do something like this:

```
if(current_user_can( 'read_post' )) {
    //show a header image
} else if(current_user_can( 'edit_post' )) {
    //show a header image
} else {
    //show standard header
}
```

Regards Tom